# Using Python select a piece of a string that conforms to a certain pattern, modify it by deleting one element, then replace the modified string

Tags: python, regex

I am putting together some code to insert nouns into carrier phrases. The way I have achieved it this results in a "floating" `'s` as such:

```
Deny your neighbor 's request.
Deny a customer 's request.
Deny your roommate 's request.
Deny your acquaintance 's request.
```

I believe this regex string is the "selector" `([a-z]\s's)` I can use to select the last letter + space + 's

It occurs to me that I can use the regex package to select the item I am interested in. What I can't figure out is how to modify the selected pattern (remove the space between the preceding word's last letter and the apostrophe s).

My code is laughable and included it here for context.

```
import regex as re

verb_list = ["Offer a compliment.", "Wish a nice day.", "Deny 's request.", 
"Ask to stop doing something", "Ask what's up with them."]
noun_list = ["your neighbor", "a customer", "your roommate", "your acquaintance", "your coworker"]
emotions = ["Disturbed", "Surprised", "Sad", "Disgusted",]

    output = {}
    # print(emotions)
    for e in emotions:
        pe = "("+e+")"
        e_list = [pe]
    
        for v in verb_list:
            v_arr = v.split()
    
            for n in noun_list:
                verb = v_arr[:1]
                predicate = [n] + v_arr[1:]
                full_string = " ".join(e_list+verb + predicate)
                output[e] = full_string
                ## re.sub(r'([a-z]\s's)', , )
    
                print(full_string)
```

Comment: I see you have a commented out line of using `re.sub`. Why does it not work?

Comment: the idea is that i have to select that regex, modify the regex and re insert it. I do not know how to do that. I know that `$1` allows me to replace the original, but I need the original minus the space.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `([a-z])\s's(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/MIMFQ9/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the example string in the question removing the space in between, you can use a capture group for the a-z part `([a-z])` and match a whitespace char followed by `'s`.

If there should be a whitspace boundary after the 's, you can use a negative lookahead assertion `(?!\S)`

In the replacement use the group and 's  `r"\1's"`

```
([a-z])\s's(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MIMFQ9/1/)

```
import re
 
regex = r"([a-z])\s's(?!\S)"
 
s = ("Deny your neighbor 's request.\n"
    "Deny a customer 's request.\n"
    "Deny your roommate 's request.\n"
    "Deny your acquaintance 's request.")
 
result = re.sub(regex, r"\1's", s)
 
if result:
    print (result)
```

Output

```
Deny your neighbor's request.
Deny a customer's request.
Deny your roommate's request.
Deny your acquaintance's request.
```

Comment: Ok, I see that rather than trying to slice out the \s, since what I am trying to put in is regular and unchanging `'s`, then you just "wrote the `'s` back in.

This will work in this case. Thank you.